# Remove Duplicates in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

When I manually removed duplicates from range (B35:F99), I got error saying I have merge cells in row 32 and 33.

How can I by pass that using VBA? I have multiple sheets to remove duplicates.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicate()
    Range("B4:F99").RemoveDuplicates Column:=Array(1,2)
End Sub
```

I got this code online and it does not work.

Comment: You will need to unmerge the cells prior to running the code.

Comment: Right, it does remove the duplicates after I unmerge the cells, however, it does not delete the duplicate values but the formula, how can I remove duplicate based on the value?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option would just be to ensure all cells are unmerged before you run the RemoveDuplicates method.

```
Sub RemoveDuplicate()
    with range("B4:F99")
        .unmerge
        .removeduplicates column:=array(1,2)
    end with
End sub
```

I'm assuming you don't need the merging to remain; if you do, you may need to loop through and record the merge areas first, then re-apply them.

Comment: Hi Werrf, Thanks for replying. I have another question, it doesn't seem like it delete the duplicates values but the formula that run the cells. How can I edit that? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cassie.L you will need to convert all the formulas to their values.  This will permenantly remove the formulas.  Add `.Value = .Value` under the `.unmerge`

Comment: @Werrf, it does changed it to Value, but I got error saying "Compile error: Named argument not found" and highlighted on Column:=

Comment: @Werrf, do you have any idea how to fix this? Could it be I am using Excel 2013? Thank you so much